# wxMaxima won't show plots

Tags: gnuplot, maxima, wxmaxima

I downloaded Maxima using Macports as per instructions on sourceforge. But every time I try to plot using wxplot2d it shows this:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
> Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gnuplot
> Reason: image not found

Please help to resolve issue, I've tried deleting and redownloading but that didn't help.

Comment: A couple of ideas. (1) Try `sudo port install fontconfig` , maybe that helps. If there's still a problem, try a web search for "macos macports fontconfig installation problem" or something like that. (2) Use Homebrew to install. Something like `brew install sbcl && brew install wxmaxima`.